# getComputedStyle() Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: javascript, css

In the following code example, I'd expect to see **underline** in the console log. Instead, I see **none**.

## How do I extract the `underline` value from the `text-decoration` property in `#one .yo`?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var $el = document.querySelectorAll('#one .yo')[0];
  var css = getComputedStyle($el).cssText;

  console.log("text-decoration is set to:");
  console.log(/text\-decoration\: ([^\;]+)/g.exec(css)?.[1] + '!');
  console.dir($el);
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle($el));

  var $el2 = document.querySelectorAll('#two .yo')[0];
  $el2.style.cssText = css;
}, 750);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#one {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div class="yo">what's up</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
  <div class="yo">what's up</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Another point of interest is that `color` is displayed properly as 0,0,255. Upon inspecting the element in Chrome, we see this: http://puu.sh/mQbtX/77032e4c1c.png (the text-decoration is grayed out for some reason, while color is not). Could this be a related issue?

Comment: @sg.cc: That's because both the color and the text decoration are applied to the parent element. So the decoration gets painted, and the painted decoration then propagates to the child element. The child element also inherits the color from its parent, but that is separate from the decoration entirely. If you set `color: black` on `*`, you'll find that the underline remains blue even though the text is black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it affects its childs, the `text-decoration` style property [of the parent] is [not inherited](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/text-decoration-css-property/) (bold is mine):

> The text decorations are **not technically inherited**, but the effect is similar to inheritance. If they’re set on an inline element, they apply to all boxes generated by that element. (...)

It seems strange because other similar properties, like `font-size`, [do inherit](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/trykse3p/), but that's just the way it is (see "Inherited: no" at the table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) and/or [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-property)).